# Access 2007 export table to csv decimal

Tags: oracle, ms-access, decimal

I have some tables in Access that I'm trying to export to csv so that I can import to Oracle. I don't use the export via ODBC because I have 70K - 500K records in some of these tables and that feature takes way to long as I have about 25 tables to do so I want to export to csv (which is much faster) then load via sqlldr.

Some numeric columns can go out to 16 decimal places and I need them all. However when I export they only go out 2. I've done some googling around this. Regional settings only allows 9 decimals out (Win XP), formatting the column via a query will change it to text which I don't want when I import to Oracle (maybe I can use to_number() in the control file?).

Why is this so difficult? Why can't Access just export numeric columns as they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Access 2007 test case, I'm not seeing quite the same result you described.  When I export to CSV, I get all the decimal places.

Here is my sample table with `decimal_field` as decimal(18, 16).

```
id some_text decimal_field
-- --------- ------------------
 1 a         1.0123456789012345
 2 b                          2
```

Unfortunately, those exported `decimal_field` values are quoted in the CSV:

```
"id","some_text","decimal_field"
1,"a","1.0123456789012345"
2,"b","2"
```

The only way I could find to remove the quotes surrounding the `decimal_field` values also removed the quotes surrounding genuine text values.

If quoted numeric values are unworkable, perhaps you could create a VBA custom CSV export procedure, where you write your values to each file line formatted as you wish.

Regarding "*Why is this so difficult?*", I suspect decimal data type as the culprit.  I don't recall encountering this type of problem with other numeric data types.  Unfortunately, that's only my speculation and won't help even if it's correct.

Comment: The table was auto number so the number of decimal places is variable between all the tables. I convert to text via Format(Field, "@") then converted back to number in the sqlldr control file via to_number(). That worked great between all the tables. I did however have to create a query for each table to do the format() conversion which sort of sucks. I suppose I could make some VBA to automatically do that for me on numeric columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a query selecting all the records from your table. Format the troublesome column by using the format function:
   `Select Format(Fieldname,"0000.00000") AS FormattedField`
   Save this query and export the **query** instead of the table.

   One disadvantage of this approach is that your numeric field is then treated as text, so you then get quotes around the exported numbers, and if you use the option not to enclose text in quotes, then any actual text fields you export in the same query lose their quotes too
2. The other (quicker, dirtier, bodge job) method is to export first into Excel and from there to text. This leaves decimal places intact, but obviously it's not very elegant.

Comment: 1. Each table can have a variable amount of decimal places and it's pretty bad to give a certain amount as I could mess it up and cut off some decimals which would be very bad. In the end I used Format(field, "@") to convert to text, then in the sqlldr control file to_number() to convert it back to number. This makes sure no matter the table or the decimal count it gets all values after the decmial without me having to find the largest number of decimals after. Note the table is auto number.